# How do I stop Remote Desktop Connection Manager v2.7 from dropping all of the rdg files when I close it?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

At some point (not sure when) `Remote Desktop Connection Manager v2.7` seemed to lose all of the .rdg files I had open in it.  The files still existed but didn't reopen upon opening the program again.

Everything in the ‘Server Tree’ disappeared.

I presently clicked `File->Save All` after opening all the files again, closed the program, opened it again, and everything appears again, but previously it did, and then did not open all of those files again.

Comment: Unclear: What appeared and when and what didn't?

Comment: @harrymc Everything in the ‘Server Tree’ disappeared.

Comment: "everything appears again, but previously it did, and then did not open all of those files again"?